# Failed to download file using for loop with open()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to download some videos, however, iterating over the links and passing them to `open()` function only downloads the first video then raise `OSError`.

Here is what is printed out

```
Downloading 1-Video1
[Downloading] 100% |###########################################| Time: 
0:03:16
[1-Introduction] Successfully Downloaded
    with open(str(file_name) + '.mp4', "wb") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "2-Video2.mp4"
```

Here is a snippet of my code

```
# iterate over a dict containing k as the stage name and v as a list of
# all the videos in that stage
for k, v in stages.items():
    make_dir(k)
    os.chdir(k)
    for i in v:
    # i[0] is the title of the video, i[1] is the video link
        video_download(i[0], i[1])

def video_download(file_name, video_link):

    with open(file_name + '.mp4', "wb") as f:

        URL = requests.get(video_link)  # , auth=(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text, 'lxml')

        video_mp4_link = soup.find('source', {'type': 'video/mp4'})['src']

        print('\n' + "Downloading %s" % file_name)

        response = requests.get(
            video_mp4_link, stream=True)
        total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')

       # check if there is a content lenght
        if total_length is None:
            f.write(response.content)
        else:
        # downloading the video with a progress bar
            dl = 0
            total_length = int(total_length)

            widgets = ['[Downloading] ', Percentage(), ' ',
                   Bar(marker='#', left='|', right='|'), ' ', ETA(), ' ']

            pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=100)
            pbar.start()

            for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                dl += len(data)
                f.write(data)
                pbar.update((dl / total_length) * 100)

            pbar.finish()
        print("[%s] Successfully Downloaded" % file_name)

# I am going to use it a lot that's why I created the following func
def make_dir(directory):
    try:
        os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

Comment: That means it can't find the file in the directory you're in

Comment: My guess is that you obfuscated the name of the file, so it is not possible to know exactly where the error comes from. but my guess is that the title of the video that you use as a filename, is not a valid file name (it may have characters you need to escape or something like this.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of the name, at first I didn't though the problem was in the name because I've used `.encode['unicode-escape']` and it didn't do anything, after removing punctuation characters manually it did work, and I've also found that windows don't allow [?,:, etc,] and some other chars.